# Remove Duplicates from range without deleting data

Tags: vba, excel

So I essentially want to take a range from one worksheet and remove the duplicates, save that range, without duplicates, as a some object in my vba code. Then paste that range into another sheet.  However, I do not want to touch any of the data in Sheet1 when removing the duplicates.

So I have something like:

```
Sub removeduplicates()
Dim rng As Range
Dim num As Long

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
     Set rng = .Range("A2").End(xldown).RemoveDuplicates
     num = rng.Row
End With

With Worksheets("Sheet4")
     .UsedRange.ClearContents
     .
     .
     .
'Need some code here to essentially paste (w/transpose) in Sheet4 Row 1 columns A to 
'to Row 1 column 'num' value. So similar to:
.Range(.Cells(1,1), .Cells(1,num))
```

Hopefully you understand what I am going for.  I probably need to use an array or something instead but I'm just stuck. And this code has probably many mistakes.  Its just after a lot of playing around.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not copy the whole range, and remove duplicates afterwards?

Comment: Some times ago I've posted [code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911333/copy-columns-data-from-multiple-excel-files-and-paste-it-in-new-excel-file/21492558#21492558) that performs similar actions, maybe it will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks both for the answers, I am going to work with the dictionary object first, and if I run into any issues probably resort to the extra copy/paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Jean-Claude has a good suggestion: copy the entire range, and then do the `.RemoveDuplicates` on the destination worksheet.

If you must do it in memory, it is possible without even using the `.RemoveDuplicates` method:

```
Sub removeduplicates()
Dim r as Range
Dim dictValues as Object

Set dictValues = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")


For each r in Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").End(xldown).Cells
    dictValues(r.Value) = r.Value
Next

With dictValues
    Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A1").Resize(1, .Count).Value = .Keys()
End With
```

**NOTE** in the event that there are mope than 16,384 unique values in the `rng` (for Excel 2007+) this will fail.

Answer (score 3):

- copy column **A** from *Sheet1* to *Sheet4*
- remove duplicates from *Sheet4* column **A**
- in *Sheet4* copy column **A** to row **#1**

.

```
Sub removeduplicates()
Dim rng As Range
Dim s1 As Worksheet, s4 As Worksheet
Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set s4 = Sheets("Sheet4")
Dim num As Long
s4.Cells.ClearContents
num = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
s1.Range("A2:A" & num).Copy s4.Range("A2")
s4.Range("A:A").removeduplicates Columns:=1
num = s4.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
s4.Range("A1:A" & num).Copy
s4.Range("B1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
End Sub
```